# I thought I'd buy a gun

Tags: verbs, would

Well, I was watching Gone Girl and there's an scene where you can see this text on Amy Elliott-Dunne's dairy (Rosamund Pike).
I've asked people that I know about it, but the only answer that I got was that it means something more like: I thought I'd (I would) like to buy a gun.
Also I was told that this is pretty common during daily conversation. I think it has a name or at least its tense has a name.
I'm not a English native speaker so I'll really appreciate if someone could advise me, and maybe if I made a mistake (grammatically or orthographically) I'd really appreciate your corrections as well.

Comment: Guns are associated with cowboys, and cowboys with cows, so I guess a dairy is as good a place as any to write such a thing ;)

Answer (score 3):

> I thought I'd buy a gun

Without context it is difficult. I can imagine several meanings.

1. I decided I would buy a gun.
2. I considered buying a gun.
3. I thought I'd like to buy a gun.

Maybe the easiest way to understand it is that it is the simple past of, "I think I'll buy a gun."

I'm not sure if that helps. It really depends on the context and even the tone of voice.

My guess is that your friends have it right in this case.

Comment: Having seen the movie the meaning is 'I decided to buy a gun'.

Answer (score 3):

This is a statement of (probable) intent.

In the present it would be "I think I will buy a gun."

In the past that becomes "I thought I would buy a gun.

Answer (score 0):

The tense there is a little bit of an oddity in English usage where past tense is used to refer to possible future events. The whole sentence is "*For Valentine's Day I thought I'd buy a gun*." The meaning is pretty close to saying *I think I'll buy a gun*. It might indicate just a slight bit more uncertainty. *I will buy a gun* indicates certainty. *I think I'll buy a gun* means it's likely. *I thought I'd buy a gun* means I'm considering it.

This is often used when making a suggestion or a request, as if indicating something that had passed through one's mind earlier. For example: *for dinner I thought we'd have chicken*, or *I wondered if you would help me when you got a chance*. For each of these it would be perfectly acceptable to use present and future tense, *I think we'll have chicken*, *I wonder if you will help me*. The past tense just makes it sound slightly more casual.